# How to copy the Renderer Present screen result into a surface or texture?

Tags: sdl2

Is it possible to copy into a `SDL_Surface` what is displayed in the screen from a `SDL_RendererPresent`?

using `SDL_GetWindowSurface` just return a black surface not the rendered scene as it is not accessing directly the video ram.

using `SDL_GetRendererTarget` if it is the "default" (the screen) is just a `NULL` value.

is there any function to copy the `SDL_RendererPresent` result into a `SDL_Surface` or even a `SDL_Texture`?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using `SDL_RenderReadPixels`, e.g.:

```
// SDL_Renderer* renderer
SDL_Window* window = SDL_RenderGetWindow(renderer);
SDL_Surface* screen_surf = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
if (SDL_RenderReadPixels(renderer, nullptr, 0, screen_surf->pixels, screen_surf->pitch) != 0)
        {
            // error use SDL_GetError()
        }

// at this point in screen_surf there is the rendered content from the screen.
```